# ZingChart - Shapes as Labels

Tags: zingchart

I need to put some additional labels on my charts, so I'm using shapes. Here is the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/z3n3qobm/91/

But I need to align the circles from the example with the labels of the X-axis. The chart must be responsive and the total of labels depends from the database.

I have a function that generates the initial position of the shapes in '%', but it misaligns when I change the window's size.

I did some calculations, but when the chart resizes it doesn't keep a fixed proportion.

Someone have an idea how to use shapes at the same position of the X-axis labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately ZingChart does not provide a way to scale shapes and labels based on sizing. Hooks are available to position labels on nodes, but not on scale items themselves.

Now there I do have a solution to your issue, but just to be clear this is more of a hack utilizing tricks with ZingChart and multiple charts. I removed the shapes in your chart and decided to replicate those circles utilizing a second chart. 
The main goal of this was to utilize a scatter chart, modify the look of each scatter node to replicate what you are trying to achieve, and to hide all the superficial items that were unnecessary (scales, removed plotarea margins). Do note that I'm using a mixed chart, one series for the scatter chart, and another for a dummy bar chart to force the scales to match how the chart above is displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeschultz/q6arebsu/1/

(Snippet below incase the jsfiddle is deleted in the future).

This can be also accomplished by combining the two charts into a single graphset, but I find working with separate charts is more flexible.

```js
var myData = {
"graphset":[
    {
        "globals":{
            "overflow":"visible"
        },
        "plot":{
            "animation":{
                "effect":"ANIMATION_EXPAND_BOTTOM",
                "sequence":null,
                "speed":10
            },
            "aspect":"jumped"
        },
        "plotarea": {
          "margin-bottom": 30
        },
        "type":"mixed",
        "series":[
            {
                "type":"bar",
                "values":[46,46,53,50],
                "background-color":"#5e36e6",
                "value-box":{
                    "placement":"bottom-in",
                    "rules":[
                        {
                            "rule":"%v==0",
                            "visible":false
                        }
                    ],
                    "thousands-separator":".",
                    "font-color":"#fff"
                },
                "palette":0
            },
            {
                "type":"bar",
                "values":[52,53,61,58],
                "background-color":"#0099cd",
                "value-box":{
                    "placement":"top",
                    "rules":[
                        {
                            "rule":"%v==0",
                            "visible":false
                        }
                    ],
                    "thousands-separator":".",
                    "font-color":"#fff"
                },
                "palette":1
            },
            {
                "type":"line",
                "values":[150,105,399,159],
                "marker":{
                    "size":0,
                    "border-width":0,
                    "background-color":"transparent"
                },
                "line-color":"#99cc33",
                "line-width":3,
                "value-box":{
                    "placement":"top",
                    "rules":[
                        {
                            "rule":"%v==0",
                            "visible":false
                        }
                    ],
                    "thousands-separator":"."
                },
                "palette":2
            }
        ],
        "background-color":"#3F0767",
        "scale-x":{
            "tick":{
                "alpha":0
            },
            "zooming":false,
            "labels":["AB","CDE","FG","HI JKL"],
            "line-width":0,
            "zoom-to":null
        },
        "scale-y":{
            "guide":{
                "alpha":0.25,
                "line-style":"solid",
                "line-color":"#5a3b77"
            },
            "short":true,
            "tick":{
                "alpha":0
            },
            "line-width":0
        },
        "scroll-x":false
    },
]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myData, 
 height: 400
});

var bubbleConfig = {
  type: 'mixed',
  backgroundColor:"#3F0767",
  scaleX: {
    visible: false
  },
  scaleY: {
    visible: false
  },
  plotarea: {
    marginTop : 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    maskTolerance: [0,0]
  },
  plot: {
    marker: {
      size: 30,
      borderColor: '#371876',
      borderWidth: 3,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    tooltip: {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  scaleY: {
    values: "0:2:1",
    visible: false
  },
  series: [
    {
      type:'scatter',
      values: [
        [0,1],
        [1,1],
        [2,1],
        [3,1]
      ],
      valueBox: {
        visible: true,
        text: 'foobar',
        fontColor: '#fff',
        fontSize: '15px',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        placement: 'over',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: '%i == 0',
            text: '35%'
          },
          {
            rule: '%i == 1',
            text: '51%'
          },
          {
            rule: '%i == 2',
            text: '15%'
          },
          {
            rule: '%i == 3',
            text: '36%'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
        {
      type:'bar',
      values: []
    }
  ]
}
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myBubbles', 
 data : bubbleConfig, 
 height: 80
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myChart"></div>
    <div id='myBubbles'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```